# truncate itemized list

Tags: lists

I would like to modify the `itemized` environment (here called `myitemized`) so that it only shows the first *N* elements of the list. Basically I would like to be able to do something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\maxlist}{3}
\begin{document}
 \begin{myitemize}
  \item First item
  \item Second item
  \item Third item
  \item Fourth item
 \end{myitemize}
\end{document}
```

and get

- First Item
- Second Item
- Third Item

where all items after `\maxlist` (3 in this example) are left out.

**EDIT**
The answer by Niel de Beaudrap answers the stated question. For my application I would like to be able to wrap the truncating environment in another environment. Something like `\newenvironment{wrapper}{\begin{truncitemize}}{\end{truncitemize}}`.

Comment: What is `myitemize`? Are the items saved in a macro?

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I was using `myitemize` to represent a modified `itemized` environment. No, the items are not saved in a macro.

Comment: For your additional requirement, you can do `\makeatletter\newenvironment{wrapper{\begin{truncitemize}\bgroup\def\@currenvir{wrapper}}\egroup\end{truncitemize}}\makeatother` which, while slightly cludgy, should do the trick. Alternatively, you could adapt the `\truncitemize` macro to take an optional argument for the name of a wrapper environment, which would provide a slightly cleaner interface. If you're confident it won't get clobbered, even a very slight redefinition of the `\begin` macro to save the name of the current (_i.e._ wrapper) environment, for use by `\truncitemize`, would do.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One can produce a solution by adapting some of the code from `amsmath.sty`. Don't worry about the details if they seem complicated, but here is some code that you can use, with some commentary.

### Code to enable the ignoring of the remaining items in a list

We need some way of collecting everything that remains in the itemized list after a certain point, where the bullet points might also have environments in them. This strongly motivates that we use code very much similar to that used by the `amsmath` environments to collect the bodies of the `align`, `gather`, and other multi-line math environments.

*Edit:* as noted by `egreg` in the comments, most of this functionality is provided by the `environ` package, which we may include to simplify the code. However, we do still need a modified version of the main macro `\collect@body`, used in the `amsmath` environments, to control what is actually done with the list items that have been collected. We give it a different name so that it doesn't conflict with the existing macro, and modify it slightly. Specifically, the new macro doesn't accept (or do anything with) an argument, and rather than actually using the contents of the source which it has collected, it executes a macro to stand in for all of the remaining items in the list. (This macro can be modified, separately, to do whatever you like, including nothing at all.)

```
\usepackage{environ}% <--- for \collect@@body, etc.

\makeatletter

\def\truncatedlist@omit{%
  \edef\process@envbody{%
    \noexpand\let\noexpand\item\noexpand\orig@item
    \noexpand\omitlistitems \noexpand\end{\@currenvir}}%
  \@envbody\@emptytoks \def\begin@stack{b}%
  \begingroup
  \expandafter\let\csname\@currenvir\endcsname\collect@@body
  \edef\process@envbody{\expandafter\noexpand\csname\@currenvir\endcsname}%
  \process@envbody
}
```

Note in particular the first line, which redefines `\item` to be the value of some macro `\orig@item`. This is because, for your truncated list environment, we will be modifying the definition of `\item`, but might like to use the original meaning of `\item` when describing what to do instead of the omitted items.

### Defining the new truncated list environment

Now we get to the point of the exercise. Define two counters:

```
\newcounter{trunclistnum}
\newcounter{trunclistlimit}
\setcounter{trunclistlimit}{3}% <--- or whatever limit you prefer
```

We also define what to do with the omitted items.

```
\def\omitlistitems{\item $\cdots$}
% or if you prefer, \def\omitlistitems{}
```

Finally, we define the list itself. The following code is basically a modification of the `itemize` environment as found in `latex.ltx`. It sets the count of the number of items to zero, and redefines `\item` to check whether the number of items exceeds the limit. If it does, it calls the macro which is used to omit the rest of the items; otherwise it calls a macro which contains the original behaviour of `\item`.

```
\let\endtruncitemize\enditemize
\def\truncitemize{%
  \ifnum \@itemdepth >\thr@@\@toodeep\else
    \c@trunclistnum=0\relax
    \let\orig@item\item
    \def\item{%
      \ifnum\c@trunclistnum<\c@trunclistlimit
        \let\@tempa\orig@item%
      \else
        \let\@tempa\truncatedlist@omit%
      \fi
      \advance\c@trunclistnum by 1%
      \@tempa}%
    \advance\@itemdepth\@ne
    \edef\@itemitem{labelitem\romannumeral\the\@itemdepth}%
    \expandafter
    \list
      \csname\@itemitem\endcsname
      {\def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}}%
  \fi}

\makeatother
```

### Demonstration

Put all of that into the pre-amble of a document, and give the following a try:

```
\begin{document}

\subsection*{Result}
A truncated itemized list:
\begin{truncitemize}
\item First item
\item Second item
\item Third item
\item Fourth item
\item Yet further items  
\end{truncitemize}
A normal itemized list:
\begin{itemize}
\item First item
\item Second item
\item Third item
\item Fourth item
\item Yet further items  
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image: output from sample code]

Comment: Very nice answer!

Comment: The `environ` package makes available the `amsmath` machinery without having to reinvent it.

Comment: @egreg: thanks for noting this, I've simplified my answer to make use of that.

Comment: I am working my way through this. What is the advantage of `\edef\process@envbody{\expandafter\noexpand\csname\@currenvir\endcsname}%` followed by `\process@envbody` over just `\collect@@body`.

Comment: @DanielE.Shub: I see why you ask. To be frank, I do not know: it looks like those definitions are a lot of busy-work, and performing the replacement you suggest seems to work in the simple working example above. I operate under the assumption that there's a subtle reason for it. This might be a reasonable question on its own about the working of `environ` or `amsmath`.

Answer (score 7):

We can let `environ` do the big work of loading the environment's content into `\BODY`. Then we redefine `\item` to advance a counter that we set to zero at the beginning of the `itemize` environment that we start; then the new `\item` checks whether the counter's value is above the threshold (`\maxlist`). In this case it lets `\ignore@to@end` gobble everything that remains (possibly printing an "omitted" item); otherwise it emits the usual `\item` that we keep in `\old@item`.

This can be even nested and the threshold can be changed locally with the optional argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}

\makeatletter

\NewEnviron{myitemize}[1][\maxlist]{%
  \begin{itemize}
  \@tempcnta=\z@
  \def\item{\advance\@tempcnta\@ne\ifnum\@tempcnta>#1\relax
    \show@omitted@items
    \expandafter\ignore@to@end
      \else
    \expandafter\old@item
      \fi}%
  \BODY\final@sentinel
  \end{itemize}}

\long\def\ignore@to@end#1\final@sentinel{}%
\let\final@sentinel\@empty
\let\old@item\item

\newif\if@show@omitted
\newcommand{\showomitted}{\@show@omittedtrue}
\newcommand{\dontshowomitted}{\@show@omittedfalse}
\newcommand{\show@omitted@items}{\if@show@omitted\old@item\relax\dots\fi}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\maxlist}{3}

\begin{document}

\begin{myitemize}\showomitted
\item Yes
\item Yes
  \begin{myitemize}\dontshowomitted
\item Yes
\item Yes
\item Yes
\item No
\item No
\item No
\end{myitemize}
\item Yes
\item No
\item No
\item No
\end{myitemize}

separator

\begin{myitemize}[5]
\item Yes
\item Yes
\item Yes
\item No
\item No
\item No
\end{myitemize}

\end{document}
```